# Creating multiple count columns conditionally from Date[] Array in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create/iterate a count for the number of returned results for multiple date ranges. I am able to generate the results I'm looking for by using the following:

```
SELECT variant, partner, COUNT(distinct eligible_dates) AS within_last_30_days 
FROM (
    SELECT partner, variant, unnest(eligible_dates) AS within_last_30_days 
    FROM product.catalog
    ) t1
    WHERE within_last_30_days > CURRENT_DATE - 30
    GROUP BY variant, partner
```

where eligible_dates is a date array column, others are text; item1 would have 4 array entries within the last 30 days (although it could have 8 in the last 90) and it would display a table like such:

```
variant | partner | within_last_30_days
________________________________________
item1   |   p1    |          4
item2   |   p2    |          3
```

Yet I'm having trouble with syntax as I'm trying to create another column that looks within the last 90 days...

```
variant | partner | within_last_30_days | within_last_90_days
______________________________________________________________
item1   |   p1    |          4          |          8
item2   |   p2    |          3          |          3
```

I am so grateful for any help offered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this just with `GROUP BY`.  A lateral join is helpful in this situation:

```
SELECT c.partner, c.variant, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN e.eligible_date > CURRENT_DATE - 30 THEN e.eligible_date END) as within_last_30_days,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN e.eligible_date > CURRENT_DATE - 90 THEN e.eligible_date END) as within_last_90_days
FROM product.catalog c CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     unnest(c.eligible_dates) as e(eligible_date)
GROUP BY c.variant, c.partner;
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks good but I am getting an error when trying to execute: 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 2: ... CURRENT_DATE - 365 THEN e.eligible_date END)::int) as within...
                                                             ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 124

Comment: Oh, nevermind, figured it out! appears those were just typo parentheses!

Comment: @Robstark . . . There is no need for the conversion.

Comment: Thanks so much! one follow up question, how do I also include rows of c.variant that are NULL on the count?

Comment: @Robstark . . . Use `LEFT JOIN LATERAL`.